# how to get to the key in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, mern

I hope you are all well

I would like to ask something that (I hope) is basic,  i have this function that is responsible for returning the filtered objects with a specific "key" variable that translates to color or size.

Well I put the color and size variables inside an array of objects, I would like to know what is the terminology I have to use now in my "item[key]" to be able to get to my "color" variable as shown in the last picture

[picture showing what key im able to get now and then what key im looking to get!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkHdd.png)

Thanks in advance for any and all help, have a nice day!

here is the code for the two functions used in this process:

```js
    const [filtros,setFiltros] = useState({});
 
 
    const gerirFiltros = (evento) =>{
    const valor = evento.target.value;
    console.log(evento.target.name + evento.target.value)
 
    if (evento.target.name === "cor" ) {
      const cor = evento.target.name
      setFiltros( {
        ...filtros,
        ["variacoes"]:[{
          [evento.target.name]:valor
        }],
      })
      
    } 
    else {
    setFiltros({
      ...filtros,
      [evento.target.name]:valor,
    }) // THIS IS JUST TO PASS TO PAGE #2 (https://pastebin.com/4GH3Mi3H) THE VARIABLE `filtros` THAT IS AN ARRAY WITH MANY FILTERS LIKE -> {marca:"Paz rodrigues"}, etc..
```

And the functio that receives the filter ( the one i think i need to change) :

```js
     useEffect(() => {
 
     categoria && 
      setProdutosFiltrados(
        produtos.filter((item) => 
          Object.entries(filtros).every(([key,value],i) =>
          //console.log("key ->" + key + "value->" + value[0].cor)  )
         item[key].includes(value)
 
          )
        )
      )
```

Comment: So just to clarify you want to compare the whole array `variacoes` and filter out if the color matched for each same index elements for the object you have?

Comment: Please update your question with code example of your attempt (not screenshots) and details about the error you are getting.

Comment: @JaivBhup the only thing im trying to accomplish here is to search within the `variacoes` array to find a match between the color within the variacoes array and the color that im passing to the function , i can do that for like preco in the screenshot.
if I wanted to return the object from the question screenshot I would just send a price filter with the value of 35 and I would be returned that specific product from the screenshot (using the item[key].includes(value) code). My question is how to return the same product from the screenshot but using `cor` inside  `variacoes` .

Comment: @RoMilton Just added for you my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `some()`

```
useEffect(() => {

 categoria && 
  setProdutosFiltrados(
    produtos.filter((item) => 
      Object.entries(filtros).every(([key,value],i) =>{
        //Here the value is an array 'variacoes' so to check colors use filter to get all the elements of 'variacoes' array;
        //Also assuming that the color you are passing will be available here as item[key]
        var allColors = item.map(i=>i.cor)
        return value.some((val)=>allColors.includes(val.cor))
       }
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: [Here is the output for this code :( ](https://imgur.com/a/h89kDSF)

im passing "Amarelo" and is returning false even tho there is 3 `variacoes` with an "Amarelo" value inside `cor`

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are passing cor. Because i am not sure how are you passing `Amarelo`

Comment: your first console.log `JSON.stringify(item[key])` does not print anything

Comment: Can you show what is `produtos` ?

Comment: Made some new changes :)

Comment: Holy mother of jesus you are a wizard, im speechless it's [ALIVE](https://tenor.com/view/victor-frankenstein-electricity-wake-up-lightning-comingalive-gif-4585969)

Comment: Thank you so much!